# В цикле из списка не удаляются экземпляры класса

Tags: python, simple-draw

В примере создается класс снежинки который добавляется в список. Проблема возникла с удалением каждой(i-той) упавшей снежинки в функции удаления remove_flakes() экземпляра класса

```py
import simple_draw as sd
import random

sd.resolution = (1400, 900)
N = 20

class SnowFlake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.choice([x_value for x_value in range(100, 1100, 50)])
        self.y = random.choice([y_value for y_value in range(800, 1900, 55)])
        self.size_ray = random.choice([size_value for size_value in range(10, 50, 2)])
        self.color = sd.COLOR_WHITE


    def draw(self, color):
        point = sd.get_point(self.x, self.y)
        sd.snowflake(center=point, length=self.size_ray, color=color) 


    def move(self):
        self.y -= 25
        delta = random.randint(-5, 5)
        self.x += delta    


    def can_fall(self):
        if self.y <= self.size_ray:
            return True


flake = SnowFlake() 


def get_flakes():
    snowflakes = []
    for i in range(0, N):
        snowflakes.append(SnowFlake())
    return snowflakes

flakes = get_flakes()

def get_fallen_flakes(snowflakes):
    # num_fallen = []
    for num in range(0, len(flakes)):
        if flake.can_fall():
            snowflakes.append(num)

    return snowflakes   


def append_flakes(fallen_flakes):
    # new_snowflakes = []
    for i in range(0, len(fallen_flakes)):
        if flake.can_fall():
            flakes.append(SnowFlake())



def remove_flakes(fallen_flakes, snowflakes):
    for i in range(len(fallen_flakes) - 1, -1, -1):
        if i in fallen_flakes:
            del snowflakes[i]

while True:
    sd.start_drawing()
    for flake in flakes:
        flake.draw(sd.background_color)   
        if not flake.can_fall():
            flake.move()
        flake.draw(sd.COLOR_WHITE)
    fallen_flakes = get_fallen_flakes(snowflakes=[])
    if fallen_flakes:
        append_flakes(fallen_flakes)
        flake.draw(sd.background_color) 
        remove_flakes(fallen_flakes, snowflakes=flakes)   

    sd.finish_drawing()
    sd.sleep(0.1)
    if sd.user_want_exit():
        break

sd.pause()
```

Comment: А как именно проблема проявляется?

Comment: в методе remove_flakes() не удаляется обьект, как бы по логике задумано каждая упавшая снежинка будет удалятся из списка. а так сейчас у меня они зависают до падения и новые падают

Comment: по сути удаляются сразу несколько до того как упадут, а не  по одной когда падают.